# I have a form and table on same page, how do i use the form to update the table. Express / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

im very new to website development and im currently stuck on this problem.

What i trying to do i create a searching page for a website. I want to use the form to allow the user to choose a location or category, and then have the same page updated with the results.

I have already created the node side, and i can get my desired results from querying my database, but when i try to render the page with my new results its like it refreshes to its default state.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Below is my html or .ejs page

```html
<form method="post" action="/search" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="newListingForm">
        <label>Keyword</label>
        <br>
        <input type ="text" name="searchKeyword">
        <br>
        <label>Location</label>
        <br>
        <select name="searchLocation">
                <option value="Default">Default</option>
                <option value="Auckland">Auckland</option>
                <option value="Wellington">Wellington</option>
                <option value="Christchurch">Christchurch</option>
                <option value="Test">Test</option>
              </select>
        <br>
        <label>Catergory</label>
        <br>
        <select name="searchCategory">
                <option value="Default">Default</option>
                <option value="Landscaping">Landscaping</option>
                <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
                <option value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
                <option value="Test">Test</option>
              </select>        
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <table>
        <% for(var i = 0; i < listingResults.length; i++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= listingResults[i].name %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= listingResults[i].serviceid %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= listingResults[i].category %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= listingResults[i].location %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= listingResults[i].description %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%for (var image in listingResults[i].imageFiles){%>
                <img src="/temp/<%= listingResults[i].imageFiles[image] %>" alt="" height="100">
                <%}%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
```

This is what i am calling in my searchroute

```js
router.get('/search', (req, res) => {
    let listingResults = [];
    const singleListing = {
        serviceid: 0,
        name: 'asd ', // Selected in step 3
        location: ' asd',
        category: ' asd',
        description: ' asd',
        imageFiles: [], // Create empty array for holding filenames for the images
    };
    listingResults.push(singleListing);
    res.render('search.ejs', { listingResults });
});

router.post('/search', findServices, renderSearchPage, (req, res) => {});

function findServices(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
    const searchParamaters = {
        location: req.body.searchLocation,
        category: req.body.searchCategory,
        keywords: req.body.searchKeywords,
    };

    console.log('search params', searchParamaters);

    let condition = [];
    const queryLocationService = `Location='${searchParamaters.location}'`;
    condition.push(queryLocationService);
    const queryCategoryService = `Category='${searchParamaters.category}'`;
    condition.push(queryCategoryService);
    condition.join(' AND ');

    let conditionString = condition.join(' AND ');
    console.log(conditionString);
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM website_user.Service WHERE ${conditionString}`;
    console.log(sql);
    connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        console.log(results);
        req.services = results;
        return next();
    });
}

function renderSearchPage(req, res) {
    let listingResults = [];
    let count = 0;
    // console.log('req length', req.services.length);
    req.services.forEach((service) => {
        // Step 4) Create a statement that will gather all the photos that are related to a aervice
        const queryPhotos = `SELECT * FROM Photo WHERE Service_ID = ${service.Service_ID}`;
        connection.query(queryPhotos, (err4, results4) => {
            // Create a singleListing object that holds the information required
            const singleListing = {
                serviceid: service.Service_ID,
                name: service.Title, // Selected in step 3
                location: service.Location,
                category: service.Category,
                description: service.Description,
                imageFiles: [], // Create empty array for holding filenames for the images
            };
            results4.forEach((element) => { // For each result of the photo query (results3):
                const filename = `${uuid()}.${element.Extension}`; // Create a filename
                singleListing.imageFiles.push(filename); // Add filename to array in singleListing object
                // Write the file to the temp directory
                fs.writeFile(`app/public/temp/${filename}`, element.Photo_Blob, (err5) => {
                    if (err5) throw err5;
                });
            });

            listingResults.push({ singleListing });
            // console.log('listing results', listingResults);
            count += 1;
            if (count === req.services.length) { // Once all the services has been looped through and added
                console.log('hit render ', listingResults);
                res.render('search.ejs', { listingResults });
                // Must be rendered in this step otherwise it wont work for some reason..
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I dont get an error, as I'm testing it with data that I know works. It just wont render the page with the returned data, rather it will render the page with just the form

Comment: are you able to print returned value in browser console ?

Comment: What would I use in the console to print that out?

Comment: <% console.log('this', JSON.stringify( listingResults , null, '\t')) %>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you call 'res.render()' inside 'forEach()' loop. It's a wrong approach. You have to call 'res.render()' just a one time. You receive 1 request, you send 1 response by 'res.render()'.

Updated. 
Sorry, I missed you wrote a condition to solve I've written before.

I guess, you should call 'res.render()' after 'forEach', not inside. It will clarify the code. And you will not miss any issue with the condition.

Updated again.

Now I've got there is callback is reason why res.render inside the forEach. I'm usually using async/await functions to avoid callback hell.

What do you send back if either  there're no available services or an error occurs?

Comment: I haven't got that far yet. I've just been testing it with data I know works. The console.log just before I call render confirms that